# Making webpage hit count/trending section for blog

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to make this simple feature of sorting by the most viewed articles in the last 24 hours.
I did this by saving the timestamp every time the webpage gets a request.

Now the most "trending" article is the one that has maximum timestamps saved in T-24 hours.

However, I don't think that this is the right way to do it as the list keeps getting bigger, and it must be slowing down the webpages (which will become noticeable after a critical number of views).

[I'm using Django]

Answer (score 1):

You can use django-hitcount. It is pretty easy and useful, I used it in many projects.

https://pypi.org/project/django-hitcount/